# Override last() method in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I have one to many relations

[image: Relations Picture]

In my User Model

```
public function user_balances(){
    return $this->hasMany(UserBalances::class);
}
```

In my User Balances Model

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(UserBalances::class);
}
```

So every time I want to retrieve the last record of user balance, I always do

```
$user = User::first();
$user->user_balances->last()
```

The issue is last() method order the records by created_at timestamp, and my user balances records is rapidly stored, so it has chance to have same timestamp. and when I want to retrieve the latest data it not synchronize.

can I override the last() method and order it by id instead of timestamp?

I have try using different way to retrieve last records by doing this

```
$user = User::first();
$user_balance_last = UserBalance::where('user_id', $user->id)->latest('id')->first();
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering my question. But what I want achieve is to override the `last()` method from `$user->user_balances->last()`. After I search a bit, the `last()` method is from Illuminate\Support\Collection class. So I can't override it from User Model. The last() function I'm using comes from the Laravel Eloquent collection, and it's not a direct method on the model itself. It's part of the underlying collection methods that Eloquent uses. When I access a relationship like $user->user_balances, Eloquent returns a collection of related models.

Comment: What I'm using now to solve this problem is to create a new method in the model to return the last data of the relationship.
`public function user_balance_last(){
    return UserBalance::where('user_id', $user->id)->latest('id')->first();
}`

Comment: Was this comment for me? You shouldn't override Laravel's shipped methods anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Define this in the relationship itself. For `latest` ones, define a new relationship because both all user balances and only latest balance would be required for building the application.

```
public function user_balances_latest(){
    return $this->hasMany(UserBalances::class)->latest('id');
}

$user = User::first();
dd($user->user_balances_latest)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create scope for the same query:

```
public function scopeLastBalance($query)
{
   return $query->user_balances()->latest('id')->first();
}
```

You can call it through:

```
$user->LastBalance();
```

Comment: scopes shouldn't execute queries, they just add to the builder ... make a normal method if you are going to call something like this

Comment: In this case we can go it through that too so it will return `lastBalance` of the user only. Agree with you and that would be fine approach to create function as @nice_dev have done.

Comment: sorry, i wasn't trying to say this was a bad idea, just a technical thing ... always nice to see people trying to use what the framework has to offer

Comment: @lagbox I appreciate your response, here to learn from talented people like you and share our knowledge with community :)